# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) ERROR

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, netbeans

I have my project which is a driver's license data base.

When the user dill out the fields, it is normal, but when the user pressed the 'Submit' button, everything is messed up.

`The error Parameter index out of range` error is shown, so here's my code.

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    String sql = "INSERT INTO dr_record_table (Driver's ID, Last Name, First Name, Middle Name, Street, Barangay, City/Municipality, Province, Country, Month, Day, Year, Gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, idTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(2, lnTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(3, fnTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(4, mnTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(5, saTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(6, baTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(7, caTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(8, paTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(9, cntryTxtFld.getText());
        pst.setString(10, String.valueOf(monthCBox.getSelectedItem()));
        pst.setString(11, String.valueOf(dayCBox.getSelectedItem()));
        pst.setString(12, String.valueOf(yearCBox.getSelectedItem()));
        pst.setString(13, getSelectedButtonText(bg));
        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry Saved!");

    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single quote in `Driver's ID`. Something like,

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO dr_record_table (Driver''s ID, Last Name, "
    + "First Name, Middle Name, Street, Barangay, City/Municipality, "
    + "Province, Country, Month, Day, Year, Gender) VALUES "
    + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I finally fixed this one! :)